# Why is a pipe interpreted as a command termination in :cexpr system('shell cmd')?

Tags: command-line, external-command

If I type:

```
:echo system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup')
```

Vim displays the output of the shell command:
`$ grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup`

Which is the list of files containing the pattern `foobar` inside the folder `~/.vim`, after removing the matches containing the pattern `backup`.

---

```
:echo expand('`grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup`')
```

Vim does the same thing (without the newline at the end).

---

```
:e `=system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup | tail -1 | cut -d: -f1')`
```

Vim edits the last file from the output of the previous shell command.

---

The last 3 commands work without escaping the pipe.
The latter is never interpreted as a command termination, probably because it's protected by the string. Maybe for the same reason this command works:

```
:echo 'hello | world'
```

But If I want to populate the quickfix list with the same shell command and I type:

```
:cexpr system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup')
```

I have the following errors:

```
E115: Missing quote: 'grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim 
E116: Invalid arguments for function system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim 
E15: Invalid expression: system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim
```

It seems that the pipe was interpreted as a command termination, and that it must be escaped:

```
:cexpr system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim \| grep -v backup')
```

The pipe is inside a string, and the command is almost identical to the first one with `:echo` where the pipe is not escaped.

Why is it suddenly interpreted as a command termination with `:cexpr system('shell cmd')`?

Comment: Strange error, for what it's worth, can you confirm that if you do `let a='grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup'` and then `:cexpr system(a)` it works ?

Comment: @Nobe4 Yes I typed your commands, and indeed it worked as expected, the quickfix list was correctly populated without any errors.

Comment: I suspect that for `cexpr`, the `|` is used to delimit the vim expression, and not the system one. so vim try to run `cexpr system('grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim` and then `grep -v backup')`, which of course fail.

Comment: @Nobe4 Yes, I think you are right. It just seems the way the pipe is parsed on the command-line is inconsistent between different Ex commands, which makes learning how to use them more complex.

Comment: I thought I found something looking at `:h :bar`, it seems that there are special cases for `|`, but unfortunately it does not match your problem...

Comment: @Nobe4 Actually, your first answer helped me a lot. I had this custom command `command! -nargs=+ PQ cexpr systemlist(<q-args>)` which didn't work as expected when I didn't escape the pipe. Now with your answer, I changed it into `command! -nargs=+ PQ let s:shell_output=systemlist(<q-args>) | cgetexpr s:shell_output | unlet s:shell_output`. And to use it, I type: `:PQ grep -IRn foobar ~/.vim | grep -v backup`. No need to escape the pipe anymore, thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, considere adding this + some informations as an answer for further reference :)

Comment: @user9433424 you can get around having to use a variable by doing `execute "cexpr " . system("...")`

Answer (score 2):

This was changed in [8.1.2401](https://github.com/vim/vim/releases/tag/v8.1.2401); now a shell pipe character does not need to be escaped anymore inside an expression containing a quoted shell command after `:cexpr` and the five other variants:

```
:cgetexpr
:caddexpr
:lexpr
:lgetexpr
:laddexpr
```

Before the patch, an unescaped shell pipe would raise `E115` and `E116`:

```
$ vim -Nu NONE
:cexpr system('grep -Rn grail '..$VIMRUNTIME..' | grep -v tag')
E115: Missing quote: '
E116: Invalid arguments for function system('grep -Rn grail '..$VIMRUNTIME..'
```

Now, the same command edits the file `$VIMRUNTIME/doc/index.txt`, and populates the quickfix list with this entry:

```
{'lnum': 1121,
 'bufnr': 2,
 'col': 0,
 'pattern': '',
 'valid': 1,
 'vcol': 0,
 'nr': -1,
 'type': '',
 'module': '',
 'text': 'You found it, Arthur!                         *holy-grail* *:smile*'}
```